# Go around doing something

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

As far as I understand, "going around doing something" means doing something again and again. I have two questions:

a- Can this phrase be used with positive situations as in the sentence 3. Does it imply something good? or the speaker complains about her going around helping people?

b- I think the sentence 2 is different from the others. I think ın sentence 2, "going around" is not metaphor he/she  literally goes around and knocks things while in the others, "going around" are used as a metaphor. Am I right?

> 1. She keeps ***going around*** ***telling*** lies about me.
> 2. Please stop ***going around*** ***knocking*** things over.
> 3. She ***goes around*** ***helping*** whomever she can.
> 4. I can't ***go around telling*** guys not to ask Amy out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Go around doing" is a completely neutral expression.  It is neither good nor bad.  You have to determine that from context.

For example, you could write your sentence 1 as the positive:

> My daughter goes around telling everyone **how much she loves me**.

However, "*keeps* going around" is slightly pejorative, because the use of "keep" implies doing something you would prefer they stop doing.  Again, the degree and nuance depend on context.  For example:

> My daughter keeps going around telling everyone how much she loves me.  **It's embarrassing.**

Sure, you would rather not be embarrassed, but it's not that bad a situation.  In fact, this statement might be a kind of "mock humility", in which you're only pretending embarrassment, when really you find her behavior endearing.

I can't really say if your sentence 2 is different from the others, as "go around" is an idiom that means "go from place to place".  I don't see a distinction between

> going from place to place telling people things

and

> going from place to place knocking things over

Of course, the second sentence might be an "exaggeration for effect".  The person might have only knocked over one thing, but you exaggeratedly act as if they "unleashed a wave of destruction" in order to accentuate your request.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer :). I would like to ask one more thing if possible. Is it possible to omit "of" in these sentences as you did in your own sentence. "It wasn’t that nice ***of*** a host family after all." and "How fun ***of*** a book do you need to keep you up all night? Your sentences was "But it's not that bad a situation."